# Unable to access struct variables through DataContext in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, wmi

I trying to create an application that prints out specific processes as well as some information about them a la process explorer. I had it previously working by accessing system.processes and storing processes into an array and feeding it into DataContext (this.DataContext = array). I tried switching to using WMI to access Commandline Arguments and now the processes go into my ListView but the information about each do not show.

My Code:

My function in C# that finds the processes and stores their information:

```
public struct Processes
{
    public string processID;
    public string commandLine;
    public string name;
}    
public void FindTestProcesses()
    {

        List<Processes> processList = new List<Processes>();
        Processes currentProcess = new Processes();

        ManagementClass mgmtClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");
            foreach (ManagementObject process in mgmtClass.GetInstances())
            {
                // Basics - process name & pid
                string processName = process["Name"].ToString().ToLower();
                if (Regex.IsMatch(processName, @"(jtest)|(java)|(testrunner)"))
                {
                    currentProcess.name = processName;
                    System.UInt32 pid = (System.UInt32)process["ProcessId"];
                    currentProcess.processID = pid.ToString();

                    // Get the command line - can be null if we don't have permissions
                    string cmdLine = null;
                    if (process["CommandLine"] != null)
                    {
                        cmdLine = process["CommandLine"].ToString();
                        currentProcess.commandLine = cmdLine;
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine("{0,6} - {1} - {2}", pid, processName, cmdLine);
                    processList.Add(currentProcess);
                }
            }
            foreach (Processes process in processList)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

            }
            this.DataContext = processList.ToArray(); 
    }
```

And my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="UnitTestViewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Unit Test Viewer" Height="350" Width="700">
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,29">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="processID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding processID}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="commandLine" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding commandLine}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Canvas>
        <Button Name="refreshButton" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Click="RefreshProcesses" ClickMode="Release" Canvas.Right="6" Canvas.Bottom="4">Refresh</Button>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I am lost to why DisplayMemberBinding no longer displays.

Comment: Is it because XAML binding accepts properties, not fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML data binding is designed to work with properties and i am not sure it supports fields.

Try changing `Processes` class declaration to use properties:

```
public struct Processes
{
     public string processID {get; set;}
     public string commandLine {get; set;}
     public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The binding refers to a property not to an indexer... So `{binding name}` would look for `process.name` and not for `process["name"]`